# Fetch data from React Component after React-Router-V4 History Push

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I am aware that a React component only calls the `constructor()` or `ComponentDidMount()` methods when the component is called the first time. Let's say I have a `fetch()` method inside a `constructor()` method, how can fetch new data if I end up inside the component from `react-router-dom` navigation, such as from `this.props.history.push()`?

Comment: you can still fetch data in `componentDidMount` of navigated route component

Comment: It's complicated. Some of it depends on how you have defined the component to be rendered in Route. Read about this [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-render-methods). Which way are you using?